# Unable to get array of objects displayed in list

Tags: node.js

I am posting just array like this `{pods: ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"]}` to the backend. when I call it on my index page, it displays like this `abc,pqr,xyz`. But I really want is each one to be in list using `<h5>` tag. like this

```
 abc
 pqr 
 xyz
```

but when I apply a loop only gives me like this:

```
a
b
c
p
..
```

My code below:

mongoose schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
pods: String})
```

index.ejs

```
<% plates.forEach(function(plate){ %>
<% var arr = plate.pods %>
<% for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { %>
 <h5> <%= arr[i] %> </h5>
<% } %>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({ pods: [String] });
```

See

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I finally got it. I was sending it as one big string. although consoling it showed me like this `{pods: ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"]}`, i was infact sending it like this to the database: `{pods: ["abc,pqr,xyz"]}`. Also figured out that we can't use `for` loops within `forEach` in javascript.